# TFS rest API- Create Work Item

Tags: c#, tfs

I am trying to create a work item using the `Microsoft.TeamFoundationService.Client` api but everytime I try to create the work item it fails with the error

> New work item updates must specify Area and Iteration node ids.

So far I have the following:

```
var connection = new VssConnection(baseUrl, vssBasicCredential);
var witClient = connection.GetClient<WorkItemTrackingHttpClient>();

var patchDocument = new JsonPatchDocument();
patchDocument.Add(new JsonPatchOperation
{
  Operation = Operation.Add,
  Path = "/Fields/System.Title",
  Value = title
});

...
var newlyCreatedUserStory = witClient.CreateWorkItemAsync(patchDocument,
                                                          testProject.Id,
                                                          "User Story").Result;
```

It is at this point the exception is thrown.  I have tried to add in the values for Area and Interation node as well:

```
        patchDocument.Add(new JsonPatchOperation
        {
            Operation = Operation.Add,
            Path = "/Fields/System.AreaId",
            Value = parentWorkItem.Fields["System.AreaId"].ToString()
        });
        patchDocument.Add(new JsonPatchOperation
        {
            Operation = Operation.Add,
            Path = "/Fields/System.AreaPath",
            Value = parentWorkItem.Fields["System.AreaPath"].ToString()
        });
        patchDocument.Add(new JsonPatchOperation
        {
            Operation = Operation.Add,
            Path = "/Fields/System.TeamProject",
            Value = parentWorkItem.Fields["System.TeamProject"].ToString()
        });
        patchDocument.Add(new JsonPatchOperation
        {
            Operation = Operation.Add,
            Path = "/Fields/System.NodeName",
            Value = parentWorkItem.Fields["System.NodeName"].ToString()
        });
        patchDocument.Add(new JsonPatchOperation
        {
            Operation = Operation.Add,
            Path = "/Fields/System.AreaLevel1",
            Value = parentWorkItem.Fields["System.AreaLevel1"].ToString()
        });
        patchDocument.Add(new JsonPatchOperation
        {
            Operation = Operation.Add,
            Path = "/Fields/System.IterationId",
            Value = parentWorkItem.Fields["System.IterationId"].ToString()
        });
        patchDocument.Add(new JsonPatchOperation
        {
            Operation = Operation.Add,
            Path = "/Fields/System.IterationPath",
            Value = parentWorkItem.Fields["System.IterationPath"].ToString()
        });
        patchDocument.Add(new JsonPatchOperation
        {
            Operation = Operation.Add,
            Path = "/Fields/System.IterationLevel1",
            Value = parentWorkItem.Fields["System.IterationLevel1"].ToString()
        });
```

Any ideas?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no `Microsoft.TeamFoundationService.Client`  api , are you using `Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client` .NET client libraries  https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/get-started/client-libraries/dotnet  ? And which TFS version are you using? This is   integrated with TFS 2015 and later and Visual Studio Team Services.

Comment: You're correct - sorry for the typo.  I am testing with Visual Studio online but it will be used with Visual Studio Team Services Server 2015.  I should probably add I am developing this in .Net core so I am using version 15.113.0-preview of the `Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client`library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to use with TFS2015. Suggest you do not test with VSTS. There maybe some difference between both such as API version.

As far as I know create work item don't need to specify Area and Iteration node ids. Just need the title. Sample code you could refer official tutorial: [Create a work item](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/work-items#create-a-work-item)

Since you are using a preview library, you could also give a try with stable version such as [Microsoft Team Foundation Server Client 14.102.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client/14.102.0)

Also add a similar question for your reference: [TFS2015 REST API Library: Create a new Work Item](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/0aa31907-ed0b-41b0-bfd8-628f6eac7e00/tfs2015-rest-api-library-create-a-new-work-item?forum=tfsworkitemtracking)

Comment: Hmmm, I had a feeling this might be the case - I really wanted to get away from having to call HttpClient but I think I might have to.  Thanks for providing an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Changing

```
Path = "/Fields/System.Title"
```

to

```
Path = "/fields/System.Title"
```

did the trick for me.

Comment: Thanks, this fixed my problem, just has to use fields instead of Fields